# Cast Queue Elements C++

Tags: c++, oop, types, casting, queue

I want to implement a custom queue class so I have done most of the work but I have a problem I want to implement casting of the type of the queue elements. Below it my code so
I am stuck how to continue implementing the casting as it should cast the elements of the queue to another type using static_cast

```
template<typename T, int N>
class Queue
{
private:
    std::vector<T> elems;

public:
    <return type> cast(void) {}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think so cuz this is my only problem

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as a member template although that would be somewhat annoying in contexts where it becomes a dependent name (it look as if you have a ring buffer; to keep things simple I'm using a `std::deque` instead):

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Queue {
    //
    std::deque<T> elems;

public:
    template <typename O>
    O cast() { return static_cast<O>(this->elems.back()); }
};

template <typename Q>
void f(Q& q) {
    q.template cast<int>(); // "template" needed because it is a dependent name
}

int main() {
    Queue<short> q;
    // ...
    q.cast<int>(); // doesn't need this annoying extra "template"
}
```

The way to avoid the necessity of the `template` in a dependent context is to not use a member function. I'd just define a `friend` function inside the `Queue` definition:

```
template <typename O>
friend O cast(Queue& q){ return static_cast<O>(q.back()); }
// ...
cast<int>(q);
```

To see it live use the [Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/4sMcWz9TK).

Comment: While this helps, what I want it to cast all of the elements not only the last one

Comment: You didn’t say what you actually wanted to cast. However: just apply the same principle to all elements!